# Prove that intersection of connected spaces is connceted.

Tags: general-topology, connectedness

> Let A and B be connected subspaces of a topological space (X,$\tau$). If A,B are not disjoint, prove that the subspace A $\cap$ B is connected.

Using the definition of connected space is that the only clopen set is the space itself, I tried proof by contradiction. Let S ($\neq A\cap B$) be clopen subset of A $\cap$ B, then there exist $U_1,U_2\in\tau$ s.t. $A\cap B\cap U_1=S,A\cap B\cap U_2=(A\cap B)\setminus S$. So $A\cap B$ is contained in $U_1\cap U_2\in\tau$. Not sure if these are useful, please give me some ideas.

Comment: I edited your post to yield a correct statement. You should have no problem with this.  As stated, there are easy counterexamples such as two horseshoes intersecting each other but yielding two isolated chunks (hence not connected).

Comment: Let $A$ be the unit circle and $B$ the $x$-axis within the two-dimensional plane. Which of $A,B,A\cap B$ are conncted?

Comment: @TheonAlexander: You _suggested_ an edit to this question, which I rejected. It is not the place of users to ensure that the statements in questions are true: counterexamples (especially unexpected ones) are very important to learning mathematics. (While there is a possibility that the OP was genuinely confused about the meaning of "intersection" and "$\cap$" and actually meant to ask about the "correct" statement, so far there is no actual evidence of this, and as such your edit was far too radical.)

Comment: Actually I find this problem from "Topology without tears" Exercise 4.1 Q11, http://www.topologywithouttears.net/topbook.pdf. Maybe someone can have a look if I've misunderstood anything?

Comment: @ᴊᴀsᴏɴ Look carefully. It *is* a union in the book.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $f(s)=e^{2 \pi i s}$ is the usual parametrization of the circle, then $A=\{f(s) : 0 \leq s \leq 1/2\}$ and $B=\{f(s) : 1/2 \leq s \leq 1\}$ are connected, but $A \cap B = \{\pm 1\}$ is not connected.

I think what you really want to prove is the following: If $A,B \subseteq X$ are connected and not disjoint, then $A \cup B$ is connected. Here is a quick proof for this: A space is connected if and only if every continuous map to the discrete space $\{0,1\}$ is constant. A continuous map $A \cup B \to \{0,1\}$ induces continuous maps $A \to \{0,1\}$ and $B \to \{0,1\}$ which agree on $A \cap B$. Both are constant, and their values agree because $A \cap B$ is non-empty. Hence, the whole map is constant.